# Is there a better way to structure Express (nodejs) application routes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have my `app.js` where I have the server created and this is where I define the main routes. I only added parts of my code.

```
const app = express();

const user = require("./routes/user/user");

app.use("/user", user);
```

In the `./routes/user/user.js` I am able to define the routes like this

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

router.get("/profile", (req, res) => {
/*some more code*/
});

router.post("/register", (req, res) => {
/*some more code*/
});

router.get("/timeline", (req, res) => {
/*some more code*/
})



module.exports = router;
```

Right now `./routes/user/user.js` is not messy, but when we add more routes it can get pretty ugly.

My goal would be to have `./routes/user/combineUserRoutes.js` where I could combine multiple requests without defining them there.

These request files would be structured something like this:

```
./routes/user/auth/register.js
./routes/user/profile/profile.js
./routes/user/timeline/index.js
```

Comment: Just use `require()` in your /user/user.js to pull in subroute functions...

Comment: or, call your aggregator file `/user/index.js` (make it do `module.exports = { auth: require('./auth'), profile: require('./profile`),` etc) and then you can just use `userRoutes = require('./user')`. But yeah: just split up your files into functional roles, and then require those parts in.